# MySQL Database Structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I am developing a stock ordering system in PHP/MySQL. Products can have multiple suppliers. Products are added to the basket by specifying the quantity required and the supplier. This is the current DB Structure:

```
Products
=========
id (PK)
name
etc...

Suppliers
==========
id (PK)
name
etc...

Product_Suppliers
=================
id (PK)
product_id (PK)
supplier_id (PK)
price

Basket
=======
product_id (PK)
quantity
product_suppliers_id
```

The Product_Suppliers table stores the different suppliers and their prices for each product.

When adding a product to the basket, it first checks to see if the product_id already exists in the Basket table - if it does then it will simply overwrite the record. If it does not exist then it will create a new record.

The product_suppliers_id field in the Basket table specifies which supplier has been selected for that particular product.

I wanted to know whether I have got the correct approach here, or whether I need to make any changes to eliminate any redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Basket`, you should have:

```
basket_id (PK)
product_id
supplier_id
quantity
price
```

`Product_Suppliers` is merely a configuration table. It has the only *the current* configuration of a product offered by a Supplier. Your `Basket` should 'know better' then pointing to `Product_Suppliers` because:

- Products can change price.
- Products can also cease to be offered by a Supplier at a given point.

Your design should allow you to query for historical data correctly, even if a product changes the price or if it's not offered by the supplier anymore.

Thus, you should not have `product_suppliers_id` in it.

Also, I don't see in your design *whose* basket that is, meaning you should also have a table for Clients or Users (or both, if users can input their own orders AND the store internal users can input orders for the clients) and the corresponding key(s) (client_id, user_id).

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for your answer. Can I just also add that Basket is only a "temporary" date store - i.e. products get added to the Basket table and then it gets cleared out once it has been printed off. The table data is not then stored permanently anywhere. Do I still need to make your changes in light of this?

Comment: In that case, Basket should only have quantity and product_suppliers_id. From product_suppliers_id you can have product_id and supplier_id.

Comment: So I should take out `product_id` and use `product_suppliers_id` instead? But then that could cause a problem, as you have stated: "Products can also cease to be offered by a Supplier at a given point."

Comment: Well, you said the Basket is temporary, didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

`product_id` seems to be redundant in `Basket` table. Also, I'd probably create a table that keeps track of different prices (surely, if prices change over the time). So I'd have:

1. `Product_Suppliers (id (PK), product_id (FK to Products), supplier_id (FK to suppliers), 
   active(flag),
   UNIQUE constraint on (product_id + supplier_id))`
2. `Product_Suppliers_Versions (id PK, product_suppliers_id(FK to Product_Suppliers), price,
   effective_date)`
3. `Basket (id PK, prodcut_supplier_version_id(FK to Product_Suppliers_Versions), quantity)`
4. `AFTER UPDATE, INSERT TRIGGER` on Product_Suppliers that copies previous version to Product_Suppliers_Versions) and prevents modification of `supplier_id and product_id` if there was at least one purchase tied to it.

Comment: But removing product_id from Basket would mean that I can't check if that product is in the basket or not. The Product_Suppliers table would keep track of prices.

Comment: `Product_Suppliers` has `product_id`, so you can get this info from it.

Answer (score 1):

This is far from final, but just to point in a certain direction.

A `Basket` may have many items, so `BasketItem` is introduced.

`BasketItemNo` is ordinal number (1,2,3 ..) for each `BasketID`.

`ItemPrice` is copied to `BasketItem.UnitPrice` in order to allow for future price changes. Any price change should not change historic basket data.

If `ProductDescription` may change too, then that also should be copied at a time of purchase.

[image]

Comment: Every user can have one basket at the time. when basket ready to submit as a order, register it in order table and that order table have order items that include product id's.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `Basket` can omit `product_id` since this is available through a join against `Product_Suppliers` on `product_suppliers_id`.  This might complicate your SQL a bit, so it may be worth keeping the value closer to where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to assign to Basket its own PK (in case you ever want a basket with several products, or the same product and different providers). You could assign a unique index to (basket_id,product_id) if you want to force one-to-one relation between products and baskets at the db level